# Как написать правильный итератор на Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Я написал следующее (взяв за основу learn.javascript.ru/iterator):

```
class MyRange {

    from: number;

    to: number;

    current: number;

    constructor(from: number, to: number) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        return this;
    }

    next() {
        if (this.current === undefined) {
            this.current = this.from;
        }
        if (this.current <= this.to) {
            return {
                done: false,
                value: this.current++
            };
        } else {
            this.current = undefined;
            return {
                done: true
            };
        }
    }

}

let range = new MyRange(0, 10);
console.log('Перебор итератора:');
for (let i of range) {
    console.log(i);
}
console.log('Поиск максимального значения:');
console.log(Math.max(...range));
```

но получил такие ошибки

> temp.ts(40,15): error TS2495: Type 'MyRange' is not an array type or a
>   string type. temp.ts(44,25): error TS2461: Type 'MyRange' is not an
>   array type.

Comment: [_When targeting an ES5 or ES3, iterators are only allowed on values of Array type. It is an error to use for..of loops on non-Array values, even if these non-Array values implement the Symbol.iterator property._](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html)